# How to speed-up git push to github.com with SSH?

Tags: git, github, ssh

As I switched a project on github.com from HTTPS to SSH, upload speed with **git push** went down from 1.1 MB/s (the max speed of my Internet access) to 30 KB/s. How can I speed-up **git push** onto github.com with SSH?

I am running GIT under Linux.

Thanks!